# Upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 to glibc 2.20 or greater

Tags: ubuntu, glibc

I have an application written in Go that is crashing frequently and I think it's related to an issue that was fixed in glibc 2.20.  My Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS has glibc 2.19 according to `ldd --version`.

I've done `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` but `ldd --version` still reports 2.19.

The glibc web site has version 2.20, 2.21 and 2.22.

Is there a way for me to use `apt-get` to install one of these newer versions?

Comment: According to [this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc) on launchpad, the current glibc package on Ubuntu is 2.21. Unfortunately, for Ubuntu 15.04 and newer only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `apt-get` doesn't install the latest version of glibc its because the guys at canonical are still testing it. As soon as they decide it's ready to launch, they'll include it in the repo, so , as for `apt-get` concerns, you can't do anything at all but wait.
You could download, compile and install [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html) by yourself in order to have the latest version, that's the normal way of installing without a package manager.

Btw, you could search an unofficial repo and add it to your repositories list just in chance it includes the latest glibc.